# Sum of the coefficients of the expansion

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Find the sum of the coefficients of the expansion:

$$\frac{(1+x)\cdot(2+x^2)\cdot(3+x^3)...(103 + x^{103})}{103!}$$

The answer says let $x=1$, is this the way to go? Why not let $x=0$ ??

Comment: Setting $x=0$ gives you the constant term in any polynomial.  Setting $x=1$ gives you the sum of coefficients in the polynomial...

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that this polynomial has some expanded form

$$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0$$

Now when we plug in $1$, we get

$$f(1)=a_n+a_{n-1}+\dots+a_1+a_0$$
which is exactly what we want.

Plugging in $0$ on the other hand gets us

$$f(0)=a_0$$
so this just gives us the constant term.

Answer (score 2):

$x = 0$ gives you the constant coefficient of the expansion.

For example, the expansion of $(1+x)\cdot(2+x^2)$ is $2+2x+x^2+x^3$.

The **coefficients** of this expansion are $(2, 2, 1, 1)$ : they are the coefficients of the polynomial. If you take $x=1$, you get $2+2+1+1$ which is the sum of the coefficients. 
$x=0$ would give you $2$, which is only the constant coefficient of the polynomial.

The fastest way to the answer is indeed taking $x=1$.